# Using String Replace Only When Value Contains no Other Characters Besides White Space

Tags: javascript, string

I am trying to return an array of objects where, for a particular property on each object, the value is not `null` and is not an empty string. Actually trimming the string in cases where it contains multiple white spaces is tricky. I've got it mostly going, but the only problem is that now my "good" string value is having it's whitespace removed as well, so two words get mushed into one.

In my use case I only want to remove the white space if there are no other characters in the string. This is what I have:

```
const goalNotes = [
  {
    "goal": {
      "lastUpdate": 1,
      "value": " ",
    },
    "guid": "4a0c6410-6668-47e0-bbf7-0d27defc7a05",
  },
   {
    "goal": {
      "lastUpdate": 1,
      "value": null,
    },
    "guid": "4a0c6410-6668-47e0-bbf7-0d27defc7a05",
  },
    {
    "goal": {
      "lastUpdate": 1,
      "value": "Something here!",
    },
    "guid": "4a0c6410-6668-47e0-bbf7-0d27defc7a05",
  }
];

let goalValues = goalNotes
  .filter(gn => gn.goal.value !== null)
  .filter(gn => gn.goal.value = gn.goal.value.replace(/\s+/g, ''))
  .filter(gn => gn.goal.value !== '');
```

What I get in the end (this is the correct object, but the value, which contained two words, has been mushed into one):

```
[{
   goal: {
     lastUpdate: 1,
     value: "Somethinghere!" // two words mushed together
   },
   guid: "4a0c6410-6668-47e0-bbf7-0d27defc7a05"
}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `array#filter` and `string#trim` to remove the empty and null string. If [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) is supported then we can use below:

```
goalNotes.filter(({goal: {value}}) => value?.trim())
```

```js
const goalNotes = [{ "goal": { "lastUpdate": 1, "value": " ", }, "guid": "4a0c6410-6668-47e0-bbf7-0d27defc7a05", }, { "goal": { "lastUpdate": 1, "value": null, }, "guid": "4a0c6410-6668-47e0-bbf7-0d27defc7a05", }, { "goal": { "lastUpdate": 1, "value": "Something here!", }, "guid": "4a0c6410-6668-47e0-bbf7-0d27defc7a05", } ],
      result = goalNotes.filter(({goal: {value}}) => value && value.trim());
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

You can also use `/\B\s+|\s+\B/g` to remove space only at the beginning and end of the string.

```js
const goalNotes = [
  {
    "goal": {
      "lastUpdate": 1,
      "value": " ",
    },
    "guid": "4a0c6410-6668-47e0-bbf7-0d27defc7a05",
  },
   {
    "goal": {
      "lastUpdate": 1,
      "value": null,
    },
    "guid": "4a0c6410-6668-47e0-bbf7-0d27defc7a05",
  },
    {
    "goal": {
      "lastUpdate": 1,
      "value": "Something here!",
    },
    "guid": "4a0c6410-6668-47e0-bbf7-0d27defc7a05",
  }
];

let goalValues = goalNotes
  .filter(gn => gn.goal.value !== null)
  .filter(gn => gn.goal.value = gn.goal.value.replace(/\B\s+|\s+\B/g, ''))
  .filter(gn => gn.goal.value !== '');
 console.log(goalValues);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This is returning all 3 objects? I just want the one returned for "Soemthing here".

Comment: I like how succinct `value && value.trim()` is; as long as type checking isn't required this doesn't need to be any more verbose.

Comment: Maybe we can also use optional chaining `value?.trim()`

Answer (score 1):

You can do all the checks in "one" `.filter()` call

```js
const goalNotes = [
  {
    "goal": {
      "lastUpdate": 1,
      "value": " ",
    },
    "guid": "4a0c6410-6668-47e0-bbf7-0d27defc7a05",
  },
   {
    "goal": {
      "lastUpdate": 1,
      "value": null,
    },
    "guid": "4a0c6410-6668-47e0-bbf7-0d27defc7a05",
  },
    {
    "goal": {
      "lastUpdate": 1,
      "value": "Something here!",
    },
    "guid": "4a0c6410-6668-47e0-bbf7-0d27defc7a05",
  }
];

const result = goalNotes.filter( item => {
    if (
        item.goal.value // check if not null or undefined
        && ( // and if it is not null or undefind..
            'string' === typeof(item.goal.value) // check if it is a  string
             && 0 !== item.goal.value.trim().length // if it is a string check trim length is not 0
        )
    ) { return item }
});


console.log(result)
```